# In Pytube, is there any way to get the highest audio quality stream?

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I was trying to make a really simple python code to get me the stream with the highest quality audio, so I first tried something like this

```
def get_highest_audio(url):
    yt = YouTube(url)
    best_audio_stream = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()[1]
    return best_audio_stream
```

Which did return a stream, but it wasn't the stream with the highest quality audio, so I tried to find a function in the pytube library.

While there was a `get_highest_resolution()` function, there was not a `get_highest_audio_resolution()` function.

So I tried to get the audio resolution by hand, but there wasn't a function that got the audio resolution of a stream.

Is there any way to create this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not remove the [1] and it will display all audio formats. From there you can select the highest one?

Comment: yeah turns out you can just use `gerattr()`

Answer (score 9):

You can just use:

```
yt.streams.get_audio_only()
```

this gets the highest bitrate audio stream. It defaults to mp4.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:  [My Github URL](https://github.com/JayRizzo/JayRizzoTools/blob/master/utub3_download3r.py)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# =============================================================================
# Created Syst: macOS Monterey 12.6 (21G115) Kernel: Darwin 21.6.0
# Created Plat: Python 3.10.8 ('v3.10.8:aaaf517424', 'Oct 11 2022 10:14:40')
# Created By  : Jeromie Kirchoff (JayRizzo)
# Created Date: Tue Jul 13 20:52:32 2021 CST
# Last ModDate: Sat Nov 26 19:56:32 2022 CST
# =============================================================================
"""This Module Has Been Build For Downloading The Highest Quality Video & Audio Of A YouTube Video."""
# =============================================================================
from os import path as ospath
from pytube import YouTube
CURRENT_HOME = ospath.expanduser('~')
VIDEO_FILE_PATH = ospath.join(CURRENT_HOME, 'Videos', 'MusicVideos')
AUDIO_FILE_PATH = ospath.join(CURRENT_HOME, 'Music',  'Downloaded')

def getYTVid(URL):
    """Get Highest Quality Video from YT URL."""
    YT = YouTube(URL)
    try:
        print(f"Downloading Video: {YT.title}")
        YTVIDEO_FILE_PATH = YT.streams.filter(only_audio=False, progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first().download(VIDEO_FILE_PATH)
        print(f"Download Video Completed: {YTVIDEO_FILE_PATH}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

def getYTAudio(URL):
    """Get Highest Quality Audio from YT URL."""
    YT = YouTube(URL)
    try:
        YTAUDIO_FILE_PATH = YT.streams.filter(only_audio=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('abr').desc().first().download(AUDIO_FILE_PATH)
        print(f"Download Video Completed: {YTAUDIO_FILE_PATH}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"Video Path: {VIDEO_FILE_PATH}")
    print(f"Audio Path: {AUDIO_FILE_PATH}")
    print("Downloading Audio: Tom MacDonald - I Wish.mp4")
    getYTAudio('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wNUjCcaGrM')  # Tom MacDonald - I Wish.mp4
    print("Downloading Audio: Tom MacDonald - \"Cancelled\".mp4")
    getYTAudio('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHBMbZdCpSk')  # Tom MacDonald - "Cancelled".mp4
    print("Downloading Audio: Tom MacDonald - Dont Look Down (uncensored).mp4")
    getYTAudio('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ex3zq_ADrNU')  # Tom MacDonald - Dont Look Down (uncensored).mp4
    print("Downloading Vid: Tom MacDonald - I Wish.mp4")
    getYTVid('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wNUjCcaGrM')  # Tom MacDonald - I Wish.mp4
    print("Downloading Vid: Tom MacDonald - \"Cancelled\".mp4")
    getYTVid('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHBMbZdCpSk')  # Tom MacDonald - "Cancelled".mp4
    print("Downloading Vid: Tom MacDonald - Dont Look Down (uncensored).mp4")
    getYTVid('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ex3zq_ADrNU')  # Tom MacDonald - Dont Look Down (uncensored).mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Arcadia_Lake said, you can confirm it in the documentation here:

https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.query.StreamQuery.get_audio_only

So using `yt.streams.get_audio_only()` would indeed be the best way.

> Get highest bitrate audio stream for given codec (defaults to mp4)

Comment: This is just reiterating/validating @Arcadia_Lake's answer. It does add the reference to the documentation, which is useful, but that would make more sense as a suggested edit to the original answer, rather than creating a duplicate answer. Can you suggest that edit to the original answer?

Comment: done, didnt know I could suggest it